# Crop whitespace pdf using R (any standalone cross platform solutions?)

Tags: r, pdf, imagemagick, knitr

I have a pdf of size A4 with an image in the center and whitespace around it. I wish to crop the whitespace and leave only the figure in the center.

I'm using R on Windows, and would like some cross-platform standalone R package solution.

#### magick

I wanted to use the magick package, but found that I can't seem to save a pdf in a vectorized (opened an issue [here](https://github.com/ropensci/magick/issues/81))

#### knitr::plot_crop

I see that knitr has a function called `plot_crop` which "Crop a plot (remove the edges) using PDFCrop or ImageMagick" When using it I get:

```
> knitr::plot_crop("plot.pdf")
pdfcrop: The Perl interpreter could not be found.
[1] "\"plot.pdf\""
Warning messages:
1: running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c pdfcrop "plot.pdf" "plot.pdf"' had status 1 
2: In shell(paste(c(cmd, args), collapse = " ")) :
  'pdfcrop "plot.pdf" "plot.pdf"' execution failed with error code 1
```

After installing perl, I get the following error the first time running the code:

```
> knitr::plot_crop("plot.pdf")
PDFCROP 1.38, 2012/11/02 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.
!!! Error: Ghostscript exited with error code 1!

======================================================================
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: C:\Users\junior\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
package repository: http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/ctan.org/tex/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
lightweight database digest: 8462e7c8aae10c40abda758bef7897f9
going to download 13358 bytes
going to install 3 file(s) (1 package(s))
downloading http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/ctan.org/tex/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/pdfcrop.tar.lzma...
13358 bytes, 12.24 KB/Sec
extracting files from pdfcrop.tar.lzma...
======================================================================
[1] "\"plot.pdf\""
Warning messages:
1: running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c pdfcrop "plot.pdf" "plot.pdf"' had status 13 
2: In shell(paste(c(cmd, args), collapse = " ")) :
  'pdfcrop "plot.pdf" "plot.pdf"' execution failed with error code 13
```

And then this error the second time trying to run the code:

```
> knitr::plot_crop("plot.pdf")
PDFCROP 1.38, 2012/11/02 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.
!!! Error: Ghostscript exited with error code 1!
[1] "\"plot.pdf\""
Warning messages:
1: running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c pdfcrop "plot.pdf" "plot.pdf"' had status 13 
2: In shell(paste(c(cmd, args), collapse = " ")) :
  'pdfcrop "plot.pdf" "plot.pdf"' execution failed with error code 13
```

#### Any alternatives?

Am I missing some other known solution? (thanks)

Comment: ImageMagick can trim the white space around an image like you have. But, unfortunately, ImageMagick is only a raster processor. Therefore it will rasterize your input PDF (via Ghostscript), trim the raster data, and then imbed the raster data into a vector PDF shell. Thus you lose your vector data. Sorry, I do not know of any vector to vector processor that will trim the white space. You might be able to re-vectorize using potrace, but I have no experience doing that.

Comment: Bummer, thanks.
I wonder if there might be some tool that could do this. I could only find pdfcrop, but it seems to be for linux only.

Answer (score 2):

The error message says:

> `pdfcrop`: The Perl interpreter could not be found.

You have to install Perl: https://www.perl.org/get.html

Comment: (p.s.: I've installed ActiveState Perl before posting the question - maybe I should restart the computer or something since it might be that it does not see perl on the PATH)

Comment: Yes, you need to make sure `perl` is on the `PATH`.

Comment: So restarting Windows got the needed parts added to the PATH, but now there is a new error, please see above in the original question.

Comment: It works fine for me on Windows. `system("pdfcrop --version")` returns v1.38. I have no idea what was wrong on your computer.